# Having trouble finding element on page with xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to access the data as shown below.

[image: HTML code]

I am using this command to capture the information but to no avail. Does anyone have any tips on where I'm going wrong?

Code trials:

```
posts = firefox.find_elements_by_xpath(//*[@id="flotGagueValue0"])
print(posts)
for post in posts:
    print(post)
```

Comment: Could you share a link to the page you are trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for ".text".

```
posts = firefox.find_elements_by_xpath(//*[@id="flotGagueValue0"]) print(posts) for post in posts: print(post.text)
```

I would write it like this for readability:

```
posts = firefox.find_elements_by_xpath(//*[@id="flotGagueValue0"])
for post in posts: 
  print(post.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to extract the text **98.72** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(firefox, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.panel-content div.singlestat-panel > div span#flotGagueValue0"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(firefox, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='panel-content']//div[@class='singlestat-panel']/div//span[@id='flotGagueValue0']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```